# How to type within an iFrame with Cypress

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress, cypress-iframe

I'm using a test site to build a Cypress E2E test framework.

I'm unable to type inside of an iFrame text area.

Here's the actual iFrame:
https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/iframe

I'm able to start a new document by clicking the file menu with the following line:

```js
    static startNewDocument() {
        cy.get('[type="button"]').contains('File').click();
        return cy.get('[role="menuitem"]').contains('New document').click();
    };
```

But I'm not able to type inside of the iFrame with the following:

```js
    static getTextArea() {
        return cy.get('iframe[id="mce_0_ifr"]');
    };
    
    iFrame.getTextArea().type('test jjhjhjhjhjhjhjh');
```

Here's a screenshot from the debug console that shows no error.  The test passes but it's not actually inserting the text I'm typing.

[image: Passing test but not actually typing in the text area of the iFrame]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<iframe>` is just an embedded browser. You'll need to find it's document, then the element that accepts the text (in this case a `<p>`).

Also, the menu item "New document" is an action that changes the DOM, so best to assert it has completed that before entering the new text.

```js
cy.visit('https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/iframe');

cy.get('[type="button"]').contains('File').click()
cy.get('[role="menuitem"]').contains('New document').click()

cy.get('iframe[id="mce_0_ifr"]')
  .its('0.contentDocument')
  .find('p')
  .should('have.text', '')

cy.get('iframe[id="mce_0_ifr"]')
  .its('0.contentDocument')
  .find('p')
  .type('typing into tiny mce')
```

[image]

---

Also be careful of constructs like

```js
return cy.get('iframe[id="mce_0_ifr"]')
```

because the returned chainer can go stale if you take action on the page (like clicking a menu).